# Sitecore dtSearch config with multiple websites

Tags: sitecore, dtsearch

How can i make Sitecore able to search 2 indexes using dtSearch?
In the Sitecore documentation I can't find anything about adding more then one index to the configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this](http://sdn.sitecore.net/FAQ/Administration/Building%20Separate%20Indexes%20for%20Multiple%20Sites%20in%20DtSearch.aspx) help? It is for 5.3, but should be valid for 6.X as well.

Comment: Yan thanks for your answer, I will try this and come back to this asap!